# How to make array from several input type text using ID of input text?

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I'm new in HTML and PHP world. I try to make a multi dimensional array with HTML input type text like this (i use CodeIgniter Framework) :

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" id="myTF[0][0]" values="A"/>
<input type="text" id="myTF[0][1]" values="B"/>
<input type="text" id="myTF[0][2]" values="C"/>
<input type="text" id="myTF[1][0]" values="D"/>
</form>
```

And i hope when i submit that form, i can use PHP code like this :

```
foreach($myTF as $index_first => $val){
 foreach($val as $index_second => $val2){
  echo($val2);
 }
}
```

Is the code above is correct? Or other way exist to do that more better?

Comment: you should use `name` not `id`

Comment: @fast-snail : if i use name , is it work if i write myTF[0][0] as the name?

Comment: i think it should work.but why don't you test it ?

Comment: @fast-snail : i have try it but in other article they use name, so i want to know what's problem if i use array id.

Comment: names (with values ) of form fields are sent to server not id

Comment: @fast-snail : can i get an example? thanks

Comment: check this https://pastebin.com/fYsqC43q

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code I would print out the $_POST data and look at the array structure. Doing it off the top of my head I plugged the data into https://3v4l.org and got this:

https://3v4l.org/hD8Bv
[image]

I may have the structure incorrect but it is a handy tool to figure out if a piece of logic will work or not.

Comment: But your array not come from HTML.

Comment: @FastSnail derp, TY for catching that. Updated link and image.

Comment: @Patrick I'm showing the the PHP results of the HTML form array you are sending. Work backwards from the results to formulate the solution form array syntax.